# redux-offline ignore middlewares when executing commit or rollback actions

Tags: redux, middleware, redux-offline

As shown at https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/pull/178#issuecomment-408795302, we are trying to use with [redux-offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline) a middleware that can dispatch new actions after their counter-parts `commit` or `rollback` are executed. Point is that these ones are not dispatched, and after debugging it, we have found that when dispatching the initial action the middleware is being used as the `dispatch()` function (probably due to how redux `composeEnhancers()` and `applyMiddleware()` function works, since they are chaining the functions), but when the `commit` action is dispatched, it's done using directly the store `dispatch()` method, so no middleware is being executed at all.

We are not fully sure if it's a fault on our side regarding `redux-offline` configuration, or a bug in `redux-offline` itself... Our store configuration is like this:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'

import reduxOfflineThunkMiddleware from './thunk-middleware'
import rootReducer from '../../reducers'

import { createUser } from '../../actions/user'

const initialState = {}

const windowCompose = (typeof window !== 'undefined') && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
const composeEnhancers = windowCompose || compose

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(reduxOfflineThunkMiddleware({ createUser })),
    offline()
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both `offline` and `applyMiddleware` are "store enhancers".  When you call `store.dispatch`, the action sequence will be:

- Processed by all the middlewares in the middleware pipeline
- Processed by `offline`
- Handled by the store itself

Because the `offline` enhancer is after the `applyMiddleware` enhancer, any actions that it dispatches internally will never go through the middleware pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, @markerikson, you solved the problem and saved us a lot of time.

Comment: Ok, we have just put the `offline()` call before `applyMiddleware()` and it worked. I just forgotten that it works as a stack an in fact the docs says [store enhancers are applied right to left](https://redux.js.org/api/compose), thank you :-)

Comment: This worked for me. Especially your comment @Piranna. Thanks!